# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException to ~/AppData\Local\Temp\unlink-test12695598880278433589.tmp file bt-cli api

Tags: java, exception, access-denied, temp, torrent

Want to download torrents via bt-cli. I tryed to launch bt-cli as module of bt parent and launch bt-cli-demo as project, but I aslways get java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException to temp files.

I tryed through Intellij Idea and through shell, all time the same problem.

Also tryed to dowload with -f and with -m keys (link to the project and keys description https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/bt)

I always get the same exception:
[exception screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXLsY.pn)

Maybe I have to change folder for temp files, but I don't know to do it

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Options options;
    try {
        options = Options.parse(args);
    } catch (OptionException e) {
        Options.printHelp(System.out);
        return;
    }

    configureLogging(options.getLogLevel());
    configureSecurity();
    registerLog4jShutdownHook();

    CliClient client = new CliClient(options);
    client.start();
}
```

all params I get from shell, api parses it and create configureation according income params. Then it starts.

Params for shell:

```
    static {
    parser = new OptionParser() {
        {
            acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("?", "h", "help")).isForHelp();
        }
    };
    metainfoFileOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("f", "file"), "Torrent metainfo file")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(File.class);

    magnetUriOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("m", "magnet"), "Magnet URI")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(String.class);

    targetDirectoryOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("d", "dir"), "Target download location")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(File.class)
            .required();

    shouldSeedOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("s", "seed"), "Continue to seed when download is complete");

    sequentialOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("S", "sequential"), "Download sequentially");

    enforceEncryptionOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("e", "encrypted"), "Enforce encryption for all connections");

    verboseOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("v", "verbose"), "Enable more verbose logging");

    traceOptionSpec = parser.accepts("trace", "Enable trace logging");

    inetAddressOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("i", "inetaddr"), "Use specific network address (possible values include IP address literal or hostname)")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(String.class);

    torrentPortOptionSpec = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("p", "port"), "Listen on specific port for incoming connections")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(Integer.class);

    dhtPortOptionSpec = parser.accepts("dhtport", "Listen on specific port for DHT messages")
            .withRequiredArg().ofType(Integer.class);

    shouldDownloadAllFiles = parser.acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("a", "all"), "Download all files (file selection will be disabled)");
}

/**
 * @throws OptionException
 */
public static Options parse(String... args) {
    OptionSet opts = parser.parse(args);

    return new Options(
            opts.valueOf(metainfoFileOptionSpec),
            opts.valueOf(magnetUriOptionSpec),
            opts.valueOf(targetDirectoryOptionSpec),
            opts.has(shouldSeedOptionSpec),
            opts.has(sequentialOptionSpec),
            opts.has(enforceEncryptionOptionSpec),
            opts.has(verboseOptionSpec),
            opts.has(traceOptionSpec),
            opts.valueOf(inetAddressOptionSpec),
            opts.valueOf(torrentPortOptionSpec),
            opts.valueOf(dhtPortOptionSpec),
            opts.has(shouldDownloadAllFiles));
}
```

Comment: So nothing in your question is related to code that you have written and it's rather about OS permissions than programming?

Comment: I used example from readme file. Okey, I am going to edit question

Comment: But you right, It's more related to OS problem, And I asked about help in that field.

Answer (score 1):

AccessDeniedException can mean lots of things. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html) says: "a file system operation is denied, typically due to a file permission or other access check", and I would pay attention to the word "other".